# Next JS locale undefined from useI18 hook when connected with sitecore for specific routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, i18next, react-i18next, sitecore-mvc

I am getting undefined while using useI18() hook which is imported from next-localization and version is **^0.12.0**.

[image: Error Img reference]

This error is happening on specific page routes which are defined by sitecore and when we change the route name from sitecore error is vanished.

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks !

tried to disable cache from next js config by passing headers in config.
headers: [
{
key: 'Cache-Control',
value: 'no-store',
},
],